# D3.js Styling a highlighted Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I am creating a highlighted table (11th Table in the below link) using D3.js 
http://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/media/which_chart_v6_final_0.pdf

So far I have managed to parse the given array to a HTML Table and pick a color to a specific row. Now I have to vary the depth of the color according to the data value it holds.

For example. Here is an array which hold the Marks of students.

```
    ['john', 10, 30, 40, 40,55 , 36, 74, 39, 29],
    ['Alex', 32, 22, 33, 24,35 , 36, 57, 28, 29],
    ['Mark', 34, 13, 43, 43,25 , 46, 67, 48, 59],
    ['Jane', 44, 25, 33, 24,15 , 26, 74,48, 59],
    ['Tina', 55, 62, 53,44,53 , 56,47, 83, 92],
    ['Lane', 67, 23, 23, 34,56 , 26, 77, 78, 79],
    ['Barry', 87, 42, 53, 84,75 , 66, 75, 28, 91],
    ['Clark', 88, 62, 37, 44,53 , 46, 73, 28, 19],
    ['Cisco', 97, 26, 63, 44,35 , 62, 27, 82, 19]

var rowLabel = ['-', 'Math', 'Science', 'History', 'English', 'IT', 'Health', 'Social','Politics', 'Physics'];
```

I need the green color to vary with 'Math' mark. That is , the entire Math column should be in green color, The highest student should have darkest green and the lowest student should have a light green and so. The process should repeat to the other columns as well. I am adding what I have done. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
var dummy = [

    ['john', 10, 30, 40, 40,55 , 36, 74, 39, 29],
    ['Alex', 32, 22, 33, 24,35 , 36, 57, 28, 29],
    ['Mark', 34, 13, 43, 43,25 , 46, 67, 48, 59],
    ['Jane', 44, 25, 33, 24,15 , 26, 74,48, 59],
    ['Tina', 55, 62, 53,44,53 , 56,47, 83, 92],
    ['Lane', 67, 23, 23, 34,56 , 26, 77, 78, 79],
    ['Barry', 87, 42, 53, 84,75 , 66, 75, 28, 91],
    ['Clark', 88, 62, 37, 44,53 , 46, 73, 28, 19],
    ['Cisco', 97, 26, 63, 44,35 , 62, 27, 82, 19]

];
var rowLabel = ['-', 'Math', 'Science', 'History', 'English', 'IT', 'Health', 'Social','Politics'];


//should use HEX but I have used name for the convenience 
    var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'purple', 'grey', 'brown', 'violet', 'cyan'];



var table = d3.select("body").append("table");

thead = table.append("thead");
tbody = table.append("tbody")


thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(rowLabel)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function(d){
        return d;
    })

var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(dummy)
    .enter()
    .append("tr");

var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
            .data(function(d,i){
                //d.shift();
                //d.unshift(rowLabel[i]);
                return d;
            })
            .enter()
            .append("td")
            .text(function(d){
                return d;
            })
            .style('background-color',function(d,i){
                return colors[i];
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but my solution uses RGBA colors and varies the Alpha channel (essentially the opacity) based on the data value. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/6yp93hp0/1/

I first re-defined your colours array in RGB format like this:

```
// Using RBG
var colors = [
    {r: 255, g: 0, b: 0},
    {r: 0, g: 255,  b: 0}, 
    {r: 0, g: 0, b: 255},
    ...
]
```

Next defined a simple `alpha` function, to convert your marks (presumably 0 - 100) as a domain to a range between 0 and 1:

```
var alpha = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 1]);
```

Finally, the `background-color` style for a cell is now defined like this:

```
.style('background-color', function (d, i) {
    return 'rgba(' + colors[i].r + ',' + colors[i].g + ',' + colors[i].b + ',' + alpha(d) + ')';
})
```

We append the calculated Alpha value to the RGB values in the `colors` array to return proper RGBA.

Quick note: If you just try to use `.style('opacity...` to vary opacity of the cell, you'll find that it affects both the background color and the text, which you don't want!

Comment: Genius. That resolved the issue. Thanks a lot for taking the time. really appreciate it. :)

Comment: One more issue, What if the marks in some column are not in the same range as other column. (eg. 0-20 ) Is there any way I can set the range of the scale dynamically?

Comment: It's easy to set and change the domain using `alpha.domain(d3.extent(...))` using a data array and optional accessor (see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent). But I've not thought of an easy way to define this per column (as opposed to per table row, or over the whole data set, both of which would be easier!). Might be worth asking as a separate question

Comment: I have come up with a temporary solution. It worked. But I'm not happy with that. Maybe I should ask it as a separate question.